# Discrete-time convolution response on matlab using for loop

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, convolution

An LTI system's Unit impulse response is defined as:

```
> n = 1:100; h = 0.08*(0.9).^n;
```

if we give input signal as:

```
> x=[zeros(1,100) ones(1,100) zeros(1,100) ones(1,100) ones(1,100)];
```

to this system. What is going to be the output signal?
And how to find this using discrete-time convolution with a matlab code using for loops?

Comment: Convolution is the most simplest of operations you can implement with a basic knowledge programming. The key is to understand how x and h overlap when one of them is flipped and shifted over the other. Start drawing on paper with simpler sequences and you should be able to implement using for loops.

Comment: After you write it using for loops, you can use the built in MATLAB ```conv``` to double check your work

Comment: Why do you want to use a for loop to do this? Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Actually, yes. :/

Comment: @Nahavt We can help you we can't (shouldn't) do your homework for you. Please show your work in what you know thus far about convolution--I suggest writing out it's equation and how you might write that out as a loop in pseudo-code, and then tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: I have completed it. Thanks to everybody for motivating.